# How to calculate the percentage of a value among values in a sliding window

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am tying to calculate the percentage of numbers 255 that I have in a dataframe column.
Since I am not interested in the total percentage but in a sliding window percentage I would like to use some built-in pandas function to speed it up.

I have already tried with a for loop, but it is very slow:

```
wndw_size = 40000 #definition of the window size
df['perc_norm'] = np.NaN #here I will save the percentage for each sliding window
list_of_perc_norm = []

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if (i + wndw_size < df.shape[0]):
        dfx = df.iloc[i:i+wndw_size]
        list_of_perc_norm.append(dfx[dfx['error_code']==255].shape[0]/dfx.shape[0])
    else:
        dfx = df.iloc[i:]
        list_of_perc_norm.append(dfx[dfx['error_code']==255].shape[0]/dfx.shape[0])

df['perc_norm'] = list_of_perc_norm
```

I also have tried to work with the pandas rolling function `df.rolling(wndw_size)` but without success.

To be more clear, below a picture of my dataframe:

[image]

Do you have any suggestion?
Thank you :)

**ACCEPTED SOLUTION**:

```
df['error_code'].eq(255).rolling(wndw_size,1).mean()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.Series([1,2,3,1,2,3,3,3,1,1,2,2,3,2,3,2]).to_frame()
>>> df

    0
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   1
4   2
5   3
6   3
7   3
8   1
9   1
10  2
11  2
12  3
13  2
14  3
15  2

>>> df.rolling(5).apply(lambda x: x.loc[x == 3].shape[0] / x.shape[0])

      0
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   0.2
5   0.4
6   0.6
7   0.6
8   0.6
9   0.6
10  0.4
11  0.2
12  0.2
13  0.2
14  0.4
15  0.4
```

Comment: Instead of the lambda, you could also check the condition and take the mean of that Boolean Series: `df[0].eq(3).rolling(5).mean()`

Comment: agree (, 8 more to go)

Comment: Thank you phi friday, your solution is technically correct but also very slow.
@ALollz your solution is terrificly fast, thank you... I will go for your suggestion :)